# Generating bubble chart using lazy_high_charts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-high-charts

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, Ruby, Rails and Highcharts, but I have muddled through well enough to get line and pie charts working using rails 4 and the lazy_high_charts gem version 1.5.0.  I can't figure out how to get a bubble chart to appear though. :(  I don't see any errors reported in my rails server log (which I think makes sense, since the problems would manifest client side).  I can't figure out if there is a client side log.  Can anyone point out my no-doubt noob mistake?

Here is my controller code:

```
bubble_series = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
@chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('bubble') do |f|
  f.title(text: 'Bubbles!')            
  f.chart(type: 'bubble', zoomType: 'xy', plotBorderWidth: 1) 
  f.series(
    data: bubble_series,
    marker: {
      fillColor: {
        radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
        stops: [ [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'], [1, 'rgba(69,114,167,0.5)'] ]
     }
   }
 )
end
```

and in my view, its referenced as:

```
<div class="span8">
  <% if @readings.any? %>
    <%= high_chart("chart", @chart) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

[Edit]
Doh.  I figured out which noob thing I did.  I failed to include the highcharts-more script on the generated page.  It worked once I added this line to the  section of my application layout .html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts-more" %>
```

I'll close my question once I'm allowed to (in ~5 hours).

Answer (score 0):

Doh.  I figured out which noob thing I did.  I failed to include the highcharts-more script on the generated page.  It worked once I added this line to the  section of my application layout .html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts-more" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I had the same issue. The graph wasn't appearing but I was seeing an 'undefined function' in the javascript console.

My problem was that I was using an old version of highcharts that didn't support the bubble graph properly.

If you're using lazy_high_charts > 1.5.1, you can get the latest highcharts version by running:

```
rake highcharts:update
```

Make sure you remove the old files is they're in a different location.